# Integrate Swift Project in An Objective-C application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i'm trying to integrate Swift Project in An Objective-C application, I added the header "project-Swift.h" and I added also @objc before Swift class,
I resolved problems of compatibility but these too I didn't find solution for them:

```
 func postCallsChangedNotification() {
        NSNotificationCenter.Default.post(name: type(of: self).CallsChangedNotification, object: self)
    }
```

**Error:** Use of unresolved identifier 'type'

```
func startSpeakerboxCall(completion: ((_success: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    // Simulate the call starting successfully
    completion?(_success: true)

    /*
        Simulate the "started connecting" and "connected" states using artificial delays, since
        the example app is not backed by a real network service
     */
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 3) {
        self.hasStartedConnecting = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 1.5) {
            self.hasConnected = true
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:** Use of unresolved identifier 'DispatchQueue'/  Use of  unresolved identifier 'DispatchWallTime'

Could any one help to find why these errors appears however this code works correctly before integration?

Comment: You can use objective-c file in swift, but reverse, I don't think

Comment: We can use files of swift  but how to change the search paths, i dont know

Comment: @iDeveloper yeah it's possible but some declarations will change to resolve that problem and that's what I'm trying to do but I didn't find a solution for these. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: @khouloud I suggest you, Start your code in Swift. Because all time objective-c will not support Swift.

Comment: @iDeveloper it's not an option for me to use Swift only, I'm trying to add new functionalities to en exist application and I have no time to start it from beginning specially when I'm still Trainee in the company

Comment: All right,  If I found something relevant/helpful , I will share. All the best.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using **Use legacy Swift Language Version > Yes**, So DispatchQueue is not available and you are compiling for Swift 2.3 not 3, you have 2 options :

- Use swift 3.
- Update your function to 2.3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can use swift files in objective c project.

Just make sure you have imported proper ProjectName.swift.h file in objective c file.

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

[Refer swift usage in objective c project](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/UsingSwiftInObjectiveC)

Comment: yeah I imported it in .m file , but it says always that ProjectName-Swift.h file not found

Comment: It will not be in project anywhere, if your project gets compile / build properly then it will be created automatically. Try building without importing and using swift code in objective C.
Once successfully this file will create then import it and use swift code in objective c.

Comment: Check what is the product module name in "Build Settings" and then Try #import "Product Module Name-Swift.h".

Comment: @RaghunandanR i checked it and I used the same name but it doesn't work and the ile does not exist